# A Secret Message In Plain(ish) Sight

Tags: cipher, word-problem

I think my math teacher is a spy. On the first day of class, they wrote *most* of a secret message on the board - teacher said there were some letters missing. They said that anyone who could solve it would get extra credit. I think they're trying to find recruits for their secret organization. I've always wanted to be a spy. Can you help me find the missing letters and the secret message?

> T B H E I A S G I R S E S A U T R Y E E _ _ _ _ !

Comment: If you want extra credit in your class, you should earn it yourself.

Comment: I like what Engineer Toast made out of this question.

Answer (score 14):

> "this is sure to be a great year" with the hidden letters "taor"

just split it into even and odd letters:

> TBHEIASGIRSESAUTRYEE -> THISISSURE__ BEAGREATYE__

with spaces:

> THIS IS SURE__, BE A GREAT YE__

the last 4 letters i just guessed

Comment: I'm not sure i would like to go to a school where this puzzle would get me extra credit in a **math** class